# No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document.

Tags: xml, java, android, eclipse

Есть две XML разметки страницы для приложения под android. Обе страницы пустые, но у одной разметка LinearLayout, а у второй TableLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >
 <TableRow android:paddingBottom="5dip">
      <TextView
        android:text="Hello"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
      />
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/RowsEditor"
        android:text="35"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:numeric="integer"
        />
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

При попытке запустить первый, все нормально и выводится чистая страничка с Hello World, во втором случае имею ошибку *No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document.*  Где я ошибаюсь, как указать корневой элемент?

**Перенесено из комментария.**

```
package dmg.dmg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DmgActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, лэйаут правильный - проблема в чем-то другом

Comment: Вот то, что работает:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Если я добавляю к стандартному выводу Hello World еще и кнопку, то тоже самое происходит. Ошибка - No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="20pt"
        android:text="Push"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Да на хрена мне ваш лэйаут - код покажите!

Answer (score 1):

Всем кто столкнулся с этой же проблемой. Ответ нашел на http://stackoverflow.com, к сожалению на англ. Смысл в том, что во время сборки и запуска в eclipse нужно переключиться на окно с файлом java кода. Там написано, что это довольно давнишняя проблема дружбы eclipse и android